# Карусель ссылок - картинок

Tags: wordpress, slider, карусель

Никак не могу найти подходящую карусель для брендов, чтобы ссылки шли в несколько строк. Должно выглядеть примерно вот так, но на скрине - костыль неудобный для редактирования. Подскажите подобную карусель, в которой клиент сам сможет добавлять элементы через админ панель

[image: Карусель]